# automatically filter dataframe by keywords

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have to filter a dataframe according to keywords added or decreased. Previously I filtered with these lines:

```
kw_s = kw_df[kw_df['transaction_description'].str.contains('tarifa') & kw_df['transaction_description'].str.contains('mensual')]

kw_s = kw_df[kw_df['transaction_description'].str.contains('tarifa') & kw_df['transaction_description'].str.contains('anual')]
```

Now I have to filter according to the keywords found in a table, for example:

kw = 'tarifa' kw, corresponds to the keyword that makes a general filter.

kwf = 'mensual' and kwf1 = 'anual' are features related to kw that further filter the data.

So it should look like this:

```
kw_s = kw_df[kw_df['transaction_description'].str.contains(kw) & kw_df['transaction_description'].str.contains(kwf)]

kw_s = kw_df[kw_df['transaction_description'].str.contains(kw) & kw_df['transaction_description'].str.contains(kwf1)]
```

however, the words used for filtering may increase from kw...kwn and kwf...kwfn, or they may decrease.

How could I automatically update the words to filter as they are added or reduced?

Answer (score 0):

You could use f-strings & `re`gexes.
Something like that:

```py
kw_df["transaction_description"].str.contains(fr"{kw}|{kwf}", regex=True)
```